# OLEDB slow when executing against access database on network drive

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm exporting data as rows in an access database located on a network drive. Currently, I use the following c# code:

```
using(OleDBCommand oleDBCommand = new oledbcommand(insertstring,conn))
{
    OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
    param.ParameterName = " .. ";
    oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
    ....
    ....
    ....                 

    foreach(Row row in rows)
    {
        oleDBCommand.parameters.add["asd"].value= row.o;
        ....
        ....

        oleDCCommand.executenonquery();
    }
}
```

which takes about a minute to export 100000 rows. But when exporting to a database located on a network drive, 
it takes about an hour. What is causing this hickup, and how to solve it?

I'm using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
EDIT: Network drive is pretty fast, in the sense that moving a 100 mb file from local to network takes in the order of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the evidence, there is no answer except network latency. What I would suggest is that you try smaller batches locally and on the network drive, and see how they perform. For example, try batches of 100, 1000, and then 10000 and compare the numbers. If the difference scales linearly, i.e., if the network drive is always sixty times slower, then it's latency. If it runs twice as slow until you hit a certain number (or maybe even a certain record), then it's something else, like a buffer being exhausted, or something else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain what latency means in this context. And why it doesn't occur when I'm moving a 100 MB file?

Comment: By latency, I mean a fixed block of time that is unrelated to the linear time needed to transfer a bit. Keep in mind that there may be multiple latencies, so it may LOOK linear at first glance. You just have to test it. As to why it wouldn't happen, it would be because of the particulars of the OLEDB network path; it wouldn't occur in transferring the 100 MB file because it's going across at a lower level in the network model.